# System.Threading.Timer won't work constantly

Tags: c#

I'm using this code to check my installed programs (appwiz.cpl) and my ipconfig, every 5 seconds.

I'm using a thread since I have a GUI and it needs to stay active.

```
public void time() {
 var time = new System.Threading.Timer(x =>
 {
  conf();
  ncpa("ipconfig /all");
 }, null, 5000, Timeout.Infinite);
}
```

I have my callback at the end of "ncpa" method, as `time();`

It works, but after a few minutes the threads will exit with code 259, and won't run anymore.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: What do you mean by callback?

Comment: I'm calling `time()` to run again, in the end of the method `ncpa()`

Comment: A timer already represents a reoccurring task, so when you call `time()` again it will start yet another timer. So every 5 seconds an additional timer is started while the others keep running (I don't see you ending them anywhere). Try removing that "callback", that might work.

Comment: The *time* variable holds a reference to the Timer object for a very short time.  Not long enough to prevent the object from getting garbage collected.  See this for yourself by calling GC.Collect() after calling time(), now it will never tick.

Comment: I've tried deleting the callback, but it only loops once, and then the thread exits with code 259.

Comment: what would be a solution for this problem? I can't seem to solve it :) thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you used "Infinite" for the periodic call, which means it won't signal periodically. Moreover, when using time in variable like this it's mays getting collected by GC after you go out of the scope of the "time" variable. Try change and make the "time" variable a field in your class.

If it's instance field, then it would considered to have no references when the object itself won't have references. If you'll make it static field, it'll be considered as a root, and the reference will be held as long as you don't change it manually.

For example:

```
   class Program
{
    private static System.Threading.Timer _timer = new Timer(_ => Console.WriteLine("Hi"), 
        null, 1000, 1000);
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: For some reason I can't get it to work, any chance you could edit your answer with the code? I think I did something wrong..

Comment: Your example does work for me! But I can't seem to use my methods conf() or ncpa() with your example, not sure why.

Comment: maybe there aren't static? try removing the "statid" modifier before the timer...

Comment: Still doesn't work for me.. weird. I've tried a lot. Can you show me how you're doing it with a method? conf() lets say